# Precarga mientras sincroniza datos en swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Estoy obteniendo datos de un API REST con Swift 2 y necesito que mientras carga la información se muestre una precarga.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar más?

Answer (score 0):

1. Librería de Tercero

   E.j. [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView)
2. Colocar un `UIActivityIndicatorView` encima de la vista cuando hay una llamada.
3. El Network Activity Indicator

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Uso:

   ```
   // Mostrar
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
   // Ocultar
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar Alamofire:https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Y mientras descarga la información agregar un UIProgressView en tu vista y cuando termine cambias la vista:

Aquí un ejemplo de la página de Alamofire.

```
Alamofire.download("https://httpbin.org/image/png")
    .downloadProgress { progress in
        print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
    .responseData { response in
        if let data = response.result.value {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
```